# SqlDataAdapter.Update not inserting the record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing batch insert using datatable, but unable to insert record in database
and DataAdapter.Update returns 0 value.

Here is my datatable

[image]

Here is the function for saving the record for datatable:

```
public long SaveImportData(DataTable importDataTable, int userUUid)
    {
        try
        {
            long result = 0;
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(DBManager.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(ReferencePricingQueryConstants.usp_RP_IMPORT_DATA, sqlConnection);
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_PRODUCT", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "PRODUCT");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_PRESENTATION", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200, "PRESENTATION");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_COUNTRY", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "COUNTRY");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_PRICE_TYPE", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "PRICE_TYPE");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_PRICE_CHANGE_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime, 38, "PRICE_CHANGE_DATE");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P_PRICE", SqlDbType.Float, 38, "PRICE");
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_USER_UUID", userUUid);
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    dataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 100; ;
                    result = dataAdapter.Update(importDataTable);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            return 0;
        }
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```js
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RP_IMPORT_DATA]
(
@P_PRODUCT NVARCHAR(100),
@P_PRESENTATION NVARCHAR(200),
@P_COUNTRY NVARCHAR(30),
@P_PRICE_TYPE NVARCHAR(30),
@P_PRICE_CHANGE_DATE DATETIME,
@P_PRICE FLOAT,
@P_USER_UUID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[IMPORTED_PRICES]
           ([PRODUCT],[PRESENTATION],[COUNTRY],[PRICE_TYPE],[PRICE_CHANGE_DATE],[PRICE],[CREATED_BY],[CREATED_TS])
     VALUES(
   @P_PRODUCT,
   @P_PRESENTATION,
   @P_COUNTRY,
   @P_PRICE_TYPE,
   @P_PRICE_CHANGE_DATE,
   @P_PRICE,
   @P_USER_UUID,
   GETDATE()
    )

END
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What does it write? What's the error?

Comment: And where is the procedure?

Comment: @Artyom: added the SP in the post and does not give any error DataAdapter.Update returns 0 value.

Comment: Are the rows marked as modified in the DataTable?

Comment: Instead of doing this: result = dataAdapter.Update(importDataTable);

You should just do this: result = dataAdapter.Insert();

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know about SqlDataAdapter, but if you try  with SQlBulkCopy it will work fast and easy. Give it a try.

Here is the documentation and you got examples there/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Pls open profiler and check whether your SP is called or not. Probably not, as your importdatatable has no new rows added, you only parametrized the insert command call, but there is no indicator for the datatable to call it. so add a new row to the datatable from code and after that your sp probably will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Go the solution:
The issue was due to Datatable row state, while reading datatable from excel RowState was set to Unchanged,as DataAdapter works on row state it was not treating dataTable rows as added

```
importDataTable.Rows[0].RowState;
```

`Unchanged`

By marking datatable rows as added it worked:

```
 foreach(DataRow row in importDataTable.Rows)
 {
            row.SetAdded();
 }
```